# Magento 2.3 add class to menu anchor tag

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to add class to the top menu item in Magento. I was able to add class to the `<li>` tag by overriding the Topmenu.php file. Now I want to add a class to the `<a>` tag too. Below is the Topmenu.php content. I have added the class `nav-item` to the `<li>` tag and it works. Similarly, I want to add a class to the `<a>` tag under the `<li>`

```
<?php

namespace Ecommerce\Menu\Block\Html;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    protected function _getMenuItemClasses(\Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $item)
    {
        $classes = [];

        $classes[] = 'level' . $item->getLevel();
        $classes[] = $item->getPositionClass();

        if ($item->getIsFirst()) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }

        if ($item->getIsActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        } elseif ($item->getHasActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'has-active';
        }

        if ($item->getIsLast()) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }

        if ($item->getClass()) {
            $classes[] = $item->getClass();
        }

        if ($item->hasChildren()) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        $classes[] = 'nav-item';

        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've try with jquery and php with your code, but i've another best way to add class.

```
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link implements SortLinkInterface {
protected $_template = 'Mymodule_Customer::my-custom-link.phtml';
```

Now you have to create the file Mymodule/Customer/view/frontend/templates/my-custom-link.phtml

```
<li class="the-class-you-want-to-use">
<a class="child" <?php echo $block->getLinkAttributes() ?>><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel())?></a>
```

another solution

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-2">
<arguments>
    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders 2</argument>
    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</argument>
    <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">my_custom_link</item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```